# Is there any plugin for Notepad++ for highlighting Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, highlighting

I am new to Ruby on Rails and Nodepad++. Do you know a plugin so Ruby and Rails codes get highlighted nicely?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 2):

There's not as far as I know, but I recommend you to have a look at [Sublime](http://sublimetext.com) text editor. It's very similar to TextMate but it works on Windows and Linux besides OS X.

Alternatively you might want to have a look at [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/), a full-featured RoR IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is already part of the default list of languages. If you want to customize the style look in Settings -> Style Configurator. There is also an online [TextMate to Notepad++](http://framework.lojcomm.com.br/tmTheme2nppStyler/) theme converter.